# How to use AWS Java SDK to get all AWS Resources tag details?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am new to the AWS so this may be the simple question.

My requirement is to get the list of all tagged and untagged AWS resources list and create a separate report for tagged resources and untagged resources in JAVA.

I can get the AWS EC2 tagged resources and untagged resources list by using **aws-java-sdk-ec2** in **JAVA**.

But it looks difficult to use separate SDK for every AWS service to get resources tag details.

AWS provides a central way to access all AWS resources tag details by using their tagging API but I dont understand how to use that in **Java**.

So How to get the list of all AWS resources without tag and list of all AWS resources with tags?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Java AWS SDK top-level dependency in your pom as mentioned here

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.327</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Secondly, you can call the [AWSResourceGroupsTaggingAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi/AWSResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.html#getResources-com.amazonaws.services.resourcegroupstaggingapi.model.GetResourcesRequest-)

For example
[GetResourcesResult API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi/AWSResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.html#getResources-com.amazonaws.services.resourcegroupstaggingapi.model.GetResourcesRequest-)

```
GetResources Result getResources(GetResourcesRequest getResourcesRequest)
```

> Returns all the tagged or previously tagged resources that are located
>   in the specified region for the AWS account. You can optionally
>   specify filters (tags and resource types) in your request, depending
>   on what information you want returned. The response includes all tags
>   that are associated with the requested
>   resources.getResources(GetResourcesRequest getResourcesRequest)
>   Returns all the tagged or previously tagged resources that are located
>   in the specified region for the AWS account. You can optionally
>   specify filters (tags and resource types) in your request, depending
>   on what information you want returned. The response includes all tags
>   that are associated with the requested resources.

You may like to use the below [AWSResourceGroupsTaggingAPIAsyncClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi/AWSResourceGroupsTaggingAPIAsyncClient.html) client, which implements this interface

Comment: we don't need to provide any aws credentials to implement the above solutions?

Comment: You need to when you initialize the AWS client. There are different ways to pass the credentials such as passing them in the code or reading from the enviornment variables.